# How to convert a list of UNIX timestamps to a list of datetime objects in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, unix-timestamp

I have a pandas dataframe `df` with a column containing UNIX timestamps in the format `1,475,761,269,562`.

When i try to convert it with 
`df["Timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Timestamp"], unit = "s")`,

I am getting 
`OverflowError: Long too big to convert`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `unit='ms'`, maybe [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) `,` to empty string:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Timestamp':['1,475,761,269,562', '1,475,761,269,562']})
print (df)
           Timestamp
0  1,475,761,269,562
1  1,475,761,269,562

df["Timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Timestamp"].str.replace(',',''), unit = "ms")
print (df)
                Timestamp
0 2016-10-06 13:41:09.562
1 2016-10-06 13:41:09.562
```